# Adding opportunity title in quotation

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm using Odoo 11 CE and I'm wondering if it's possible to add opportunity title from CRM in the quotation?

If it's can be added in qweb repot then what is the field name for opportunity title. Or is there any other way to do this?

Appreciate all your help and support. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add an opportunity to the quotation form view. The field name is "**opportunity_id**" and you can add it to the form view using "Edit Form View".

The good practice is to make a module for that so the field won't disappear after an update.

THere is a module for that for 5 EUR:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/opportunities_on_so_form/

Feel free to ask if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks a lot Piotr. This module will be useful for me. Cheers

Comment: You are welcome. I left some useful comments inside the module for better understanding what is happening behind